# Decreasing Font Size If Text Is Too Long

Tags: javascript

I want to change the font size to 36px if my h1 has more than two words and keep it as is if not.

This is my code:

```
window.addEvent('domready',function() {
    
        var $quote = ('#header .col-sm-12 h1');
    
        var $numWords = $quote.get('text').split(' ').length; 
    
        if (2 < $numWords) {
                $quote.setStyle('font-size','36px'); }
});
```

However, it doesn't work. What's wrong with it?

The site in question is 6wo.de

Please note: Changing the size via CSS by using the viewport unit is not an option in this case.

Comment: JavaScript is one word, not two.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's not `addEvent` but `addEventListener`. Then you probably mean `DOMContentLoaded`, because `domready` is not an event.

To make the title smaller give an id or class to identify it easier in JavaScript.

```
<h1 id="page-title">My page title</h1>
```

Now you can make the title smaller like this.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const title = $('#page-title');

    var numWords = title.text().split(' ').length; 

    if (numWords > 2) {
        title.css('font-size', '36px');
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to give an id to the title for some reason, you can do like this.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const title = $('#header .bottom-header h1');

    var numWords = title.text().split(' ').length; 

    if (numWords > 2) {
        title.css('font-size', '36px');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reaching back :) I added your code but it still does not appear to be working. The class I'm refering to is .col-sm-12 h1, you can see what's going on at https://6wo.de/aktuelles/die-siegerinnen-stehen-fest-berliner-schuelerzeitungswettbewerb-2020-2021/

Comment: Hello Tobi. In my example, I gave an id to the `h1` element. But on your page source, I can't see the id on title. But you can refer to the title also with `#header .bottom-header h1`. So instead of `const title = $('#page-title');` you type `const title = $('#header .bottom-header h1');`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried changing it from `.col-sm-12 h1` to what you suggested but it still doesn't seem to do anything. Any more ideas?